# ActiveMQ for caching invalidation messages using JMS for SDL Tridion sites 9.1

Tags: jms

This question is opened to confirm the understanding and to gain more insight on ActiveMQ for caching Invalidation(JMS Cache Implementation).

**Please find the steps followed to  configure the caching Invalidation using JMS**

1. JndiContext is added to  cd_storage_conf.XML for two of the services i.e DEPLOYER and CONTENT
2. Logback.xml to configure log on both the services as mentioned in step 1
3. Checked on the ActiveMQ folder for JAR files for the two services
4. Checked on the invalidation message in the trace log.

**My Queries**

Will the **DISCOVERY** service also need JndiContext setting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer to your question - No, only deployer and content service needs to be enabled Tridion object caching with ActiveMQ.